# Android Api 8. Get x and y from a View, and Set x and y on a Button

Tags: android, button, view, set, coordinates

­I'm coding with API 8.
I need to get coordinates X and Y from a View and and set them as the coordinates of a new Button.
I tried different ways but nothing works....

The setX and getX method works only from api level 11, I need a way to do that on API8.

This is my method that allow to create a draggable copy of a button (this copy is an imageview and when I drop it became a new button)

```
public boolean dragCopy(View view, MotionEvent me, Button bt){ 

        int x,y,w,h,id,t,l;
        int cont=-1;
        int coord[] = new int[2];


        bt2=new Button(this);


        id = bt.getId();
        bt2.setId(id);

        Resources res = getResources();

        cont = FindCont(bt, vector); 

        dr = getLetter(bt, dr,  res, vector, cont);
        w=dr.getIntrinsicWidth();
        h=dr.getIntrinsicHeight();


        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //clicked on the button. DRAG START
            status = START_DRAGGING;
            image = new ImageView(this);

            //set image drawable
            image.setImageDrawable(dr);
            image.setPadding((int)bt.getLeft(),(int)bt.getTop(), 0, 0);
            layout.addView(image, params);


        }
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            //button released. DROP
                        status = STOP_DRAGGING;
            x = (int) me.getRawX();
            y = (int) me.getRawY();

                        //create button compy from image
            bt2.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
            bt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        //PROBLEMS  
            t= image.getTop();
            l= image.getLeft();
            bt2.setPadding(l, t, 0, 0);
            System.out.println("**************** T: "+t +"--- L: "+l);
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bt2.setLayoutParams(image.getLayoutParams());

                bt2.setWidth(w);
            bt2.setHeight(h);

            layout.addView(bt2);
                bt2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bt2.setOnTouchListener(this);
            bt2.invalidate(); 
            image.invalidate();


        } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                        //i'm moving the image
            if (status == START_DRAGGING) {

                image.setPadding((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY(), 0, 0);
                image.invalidate();

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to do it this way? I think setting a View's position like this is generally frowned upon in Android, as it is very difficult to get it right for all screens.

Comment: i need to emulate the drag and drop listener that isn't provided for api 8

Comment: i still need a solution, possibly whitout a custom layout, or if this is the only way, please tell me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've recreate my drag and drop using andengine. Works great and better than before

Answer (score 5):

you could try getTop() and getLeft()?

Comment: and how i'll set this value on the button?

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried this, but I think it will work:

```
int buttonX = 50; // Arbitrary values - use whatever you want
int buttonY = 100;
int viewX = myView.getLeft();
int viewY = myView.getTop();

Button newButton = new Button();
newButton.setPadding(buttonX - viewX, buttonY - viewY, 0, 0);
// Other button setup
```

That will set it to an absolute position of (50,100) on the screen. If you want it to be (50,100) relative to the corner of your layout then use this:

```
int buttonX = 50; // Arbitrary values - use whatever you want
int buttonY = 100;

Button newButton = new Button();
newButton.setPadding(buttonX, buttonY, 0, 0);
// Other button setup
```

This will only work on layouts that don't automatically position their child content, such as RelativeLayout.

Comment: i've got this error
"The method setTop(int) is undefined for the type Button"

Comment: Oh, you're right. That's also not available until setX and setY are. Sorry.

Comment: I've updated my answer to a technique that I think will work for you.

Comment: i use a framelayout and whit your method the button appear in the upper corner.

i've done something like that

`t= image.getTop();

l= image.getLeft();

bt2.setPadding(l, t, 0, 0);
    System.out.println("**************** T: "+t +"--- L: "+l);`

where "bt2" is a button and "image" an imageview. 
but the system out always return me the value equals to 0.

i'll add the entire method above.

Comment: At the point where you are getting top and left they probably haven't been calculated yet. You might have to create a custom layout that extends FrameLayout. In your custom layout you can override `onLayout()` to set the positions of child views.