# How to show an image at random points on the screen, below API level 11 ? -Android

Tags: android, view, position

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Say I have an image, a ball or something. I want to display this image at random points on the screen and the user is supposed to click them.

With API 11+, I'd use this:

```
TextView ttvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt);
ttvv.setY(__ A random float__);
ttvv.setX(__ A random float__);
```

And I'd get the screen dimensions, like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
float Y = rnd.nextFloat(ScreenHeight);
float X = rnd.nextFloat(ScreenWidth);
```

So the image pops up at random positions and I can obviously make it in/visible as needed.

But the above is only valid for API 11+.

I need to do this for API 8, and I'm unable to find identical functions for the same (or similar questions on SO itself).

Is there an equivalent for these functions in API 8?

Comment: Hmm, did you try the suggestions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869604/android-api-8-get-x-and-y-from-a-view-and-set-x-and-y-on-a-button?rq=1)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit different but more straight forward, if you like.

First you have to occupy the space where you want to show the image or text. Do this with a SurfaceView or ImageView. You place in there your own drawable in which you override the `paint()` method. In the paint method you get a Canvas object in which you can draw text, bitmaps or any shape. And you can place within the canvas where you like.

If you're interested, I can show you some sample code. It just needs some till I'm back on my desk. So let me know if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Use the next code to change the position of your view changing the left and top margins.

```
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)yourView.getLayoutParams();
    params.leftMargin = x;
    params.topMargin = y;
    yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Your view has to be in RelativeLayout positioned in the top left corner like this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/your_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

**Note:** x and y will be the coordinates of the top left corner of your view.