# How to get the coordinates of a button in android?

Tags: android, button, coordinates

I want to get the coordinate positions of a button in my application.I used the following method.But its not working.Please help.

```
public Point currentPosition(View view)
    {
        int[] loc = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
        int x = loc[0];
        int y=loc[1];
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"coordinate is"+x+","+y,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return new Point(loc[0], loc[1]);

    }
```

Also i used this

```
 btn_show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
              @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) 
             {
                   int x = (int)btn_show.getX();
                   int y=  (int)btn_show.getY();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button x is......"+x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button y is......"+y,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
 }
           });
```

Comment: Try this, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869604/android-api-8-get-x-and-y-from-a-view-and-set-x-and-y-on-a-button

Comment: what i need is to get the coordinate position,not setting the position

Comment: myView.getLeft(); is actually getting the x-axis and myView.getTop(); is returning the y-axis.

Comment: Are you trying that in the onCreate method ? You need to wait for the view to be rendered.

Comment: I tried lot of methods for this.None of them is working :(

Answer (score 0):

The method you use expect integer values as references of R.string.whatever. Cast the getTop() return value to String should work.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(button1.getTop()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

To get the x/y of the button (since API 11):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (int)button1.getX() + ":" + (int)button1.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Doc:

The visual x position of this view, in pixels.

For API below 11 you are on the right way: getTop() is the equivalent of getY() but without a possible animation/translation. getLeft() is the quivalent of getX() with the same restriction.

or

You can use View.getTop(), View.getBottom(), View.getLeft(), and View.getRight(). These will return the location of the top, bottom, left and right edge of the View relative to the parent.

or Use

```
View.getLocationOnScreen()
```

and/or

```
getLocationInWindow().
```

If you are using onTouch lister means use this one.
code for your onTouch method:

```
float screenX = v.getLeft() + event.getX();   // X in Screen Coordinates
float screenY = v.getTop() + event.getY();    // Y in Screen Coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the `View` is measured, otherwise it will always return 0. Use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener`:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int x = view.getLeft();
        int y = view.getTop();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to get the coordinator position.
If you want to center a floating button such as a tutorial with tourguide library.

I suggest create this method

```
public Rect getRectFromAView(View view){
   Rect rect=new Rect(); // create a new rect
   view.getGlobalRect(rect);// draw the rect 
   return rect;
}
```

If I want to get the coordinate position of x or y

```
Rect rect=getREctFromAView(view);
rect.exactCenterX(); //Return the position X
rect.exactCenterY(); //Return the position Y
```

This is the case when I try to get the center position of a view.

Answer (score -1):

try :-

```
 float x = button.getX();
 float y = button.getY();
```